# Observables involving other observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an issue where one of my observables depends on another observable, but when the parent observable is updated, the child does not appear to be updated.

**ClientService (parent)**

```
@Injectable()
export class ClientService {

  private client =  new BehaviorSubject("");
  clientStream$ = this.client.asObservable();

  }
}
```

**CommentService (child)**

```
@Injectable()
export class CommentsProvider {
  private client$: Observable<any>;
  private comments = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  comments$: Observable<any[]>

  constructor(private clientService: ClientService) {
    this.initializeComments()
  }

  initializeComments() {
    this.client$ = this.clientService.clientStream$
    this.comments$ = this.comments.asObservable()

    this.client$.subscribe( client => {
      for ( let comment of client.comments ) {
        this.addComment(comment)
      }
    })
  }

  addComment(comment) {
    let commentArray = _.cloneDeep(this.comments.getValue());
    commentArray.push(comment)
    this.comments.next(commentArray)
  }

  getComments() : Observable<any[]> {
    return this.comments$
  }
}
```

And in my view component I call:

```
`this.comments$ = this.commentService.getComments();`
```

and display the results using:

```
*ngIf="this.comments$ | async as comments ..."
```

If I make a call to `addComment()`, the array is updated, however, when I add a comment to `client.comments`, the array is **not** updated.  Would there be a way to notify subscribers of the change to `client.comments`?

Comment: How are your services provided? are they both singleton services (app wide)?

Comment: yes, they are.  Should they be something else?

Comment: na, singletons should be good. Can you add the your code to ClientService for `when I add a comment to client.comments, the array is not updated`

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but there's nothing in ClientService to add to the BehaviorSubject.

```js
@Injectable()
export class ClientService {

  private client =  new BehaviorSubject("");
  clientStream$ = this.client.asObservable();

  }
}
```

Variable `client` is private, so can't be accessed outside the class.
`clientStream$` is `asObservable()`, so you can't `.next(newVale)` to give it new value (at least I think that's the point of asObservable).
Did you only paste part of ClientService? - there's two closing curley's but only one opening curley.

Maybe add this method to ClientService,

```js
addClient(newClient) {
  client.next(newClient);
}
```